# With Vagrant, is it possible to run a single VM (scotchbox) using multiple Vagrantfiles?

Tags: vagrant, virtual-machine

I currently have multiple dev sites that each use Vagrant and scotchbox. Each site directory has its own copy of scotchbox, but since they're all the same I'd like to have just one scotchbox VM that I can start with any Vagrantfile, where each Vagrantfile would just change the `config.vm.synced_folder`.

So, for example, let's say I have:

```
~/Sites/cheese/
~/Sites/bacon/
~/Sites/eggs/
```

and then

`~/Sites/sctoch-box`

I'd like to be able to startup and shutdown Vagrant from `~/Sites/cheese/` or `~/Sites/bacon/` and so on without each also having their own copy of scotch-box.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you could potentially do that - I've not tested and don't think its official supported

but you can create the first VM from your Vagrantfile within the `~/Sites/cheese/` project, once you have created the VM, copy the Vagrant file and `.vagrant` directory from `~/Sites/cheese/` into `~/Sites/bacon/` and `~/Sites/egges/` so all will point to the same VM. Edit your `Vagrantfile` within each of your project to change the Vagrantfile if needed.

You will be able to start the VM from any of this project, but as its single VM, if you try to run `vagrant` from another project directory, it will not work.